# Itô lemma use in proof of Feynman-Kac formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

The [Wiki article on the Feynman-Kac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula) says:

> Applying Itô's Lemma to the process
>   $$Y(s) = e^{-\int_t^s V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau} u(X_s,s)+ \int_t^s e^{-\int_t^r V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}f(X_r,r)dr$$
>   one gets
>   \begin{align}dY = {} & d\left(e^{-  \int_t^s V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}\right) u(X_s,s) + e^{-  \int_t^s V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}\,du(X_s,s) \\[6pt]
> & {} + d\left(e^{-  \int_t^s V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}\right)du(X_s,s) + d\left(\int_t^s e^{-  \int_t^r V(X_\tau,\tau)\, d\tau}  f(X_r,r) \, dr\right)\end{align}

I know what [Itô's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma#Mathematical_formulation_of_It.C3.B4.27s_lemma) says, but I can't see how it relates here. What's our '$f$'? What was the drift and diffusion terms? I can't see anything that resembles them in the definition of $Y$.

Comment: You are essentially given $u$ (the solution to the PDE), and you are given $f$ and $V$. Then they're using Ito's lemma but not the one for solutions to standard SDEs, just the one which tells us that the differential of a product of two processes is given by the two "product rule" terms (the first two terms) plus the quadratic covariation (the third term).

Comment: Thanks @Ian - got it now. I found this other answer of yours, which helped a lot, so thanks for that too http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250352/how-do-we-apply-itos-lemma-to-a-product-of-functions